# Applying Loops on Levels

Tags: r, csv

I have a huge csv file of sports (EPL) data which encompasses player performance in every game for their respective teams. I would like to run a loop to compare the amount of times a team has scored first in a match (the data is called `First.Goal`).

I know how to calculate them individually, e.g for Liverpool from a csv called `Prem1112`:

```
Prem<-read.csv("Prem1112.csv")

sum(subset(Prem,Team=='Liverpool',First.Goal))
```

Ideally I'd like to run the loop so I wouldn't have to calculate all 20 teams individually. Any ideas?

Comment: `xtabs`, `aggregate`, `by`, `tapply`, `ddply`...

Comment: A sample file would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
aggregate(First.Goal ~ Team, Prem, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped! I guess with R I wouldn't have to worry much about looping.

Comment: @ClattyCake Right, there are many functions in R that help solving problems without `for` loops.

Comment: And when there is no dedicated function, `apply` loops are often preferable to `for` loops.